# Azure B2C Custom Policy with partner IDP Missing Claims when redeeming refresh token

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure B2C with custom policies to provide OIDC authentication to a desktop client (IdentityModel).  I am populating the JWT with a number of claims from the federated IDP.  I receive all of these claims in the AccessToken when logging in.

However, when I later try to redeem my RefreshToken for a fresh AccessToken, the additional claims are not populated.  I thought the new access token would automatically be populated with the claims from the original access token?

But honestly, I'd settle for just getting the email claim.  I can see the email stored under users in my Azure portal under "userPrincipalName" so I know it's in the Active Directory.

But I can't figure out how to retrieve it in my AccessToken when redeeming my RefreshToken.